# Logins in Roundcube stand-alone version

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel, roundcube

I have a stand alone Roundcube installation that I have installed on the server. I have it set up, for the most part, correctly. I can send and receive emails with it and such. I can even use an IMAP script to check the amount of inbox messages for that account. But here is my confusion and question.

In my main.inc.php file of Roundcube, I have this set:

```
// automatically create a new Roundcube user when log-in the first time.
// a new user will be created once the IMAP login succeeds.
// set to false if only registered users can use this service
   $rcmail_config['auto_create_user'] = false;
```

But when I attempt to login to the stand alone version of roundcube after creating an email within the cPanel account for a new user, it fails. So my confusion is this.

All the years that I have been doing this, I know that I 'must' create an email within cPanel in order for that email address to become valid on the server it resides on, and usable. But how can I make it so that Roundcube is actually checking against the server for emails, and not in it's own stand alone version? Because if I set the above variable to 'true', it works, because of the auto create user, and while it works within Roundcube, it doesn't show up in cPanel as an email address. So I am confused on how to get this configured so Roundcube works with cPanel in regards to emails and connectivity.